# Swift - stripe with firebase could not parse the ephemeral key response following protocol STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider

Tags: swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe with firebase and swift to store the user's credit card. Currently, I'm creating the user within stripe when the user is created in firebase but for some reason, I'm getting this error `Could not parse the ephemeral key response following protocol STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider` when trying to present the `PaymentOptionsViewController`

**Presentation:**

```
var backendBaseURL: String? = "https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/"

var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext?

MyAPIClient.sharedClient.baseURLString = self.backendBaseURL

let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient.sharedClient)
let paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)
paymentContext.hostViewController = self
paymentContext.presentPaymentOptionsViewController()
```

**API Client:**

```
enum APIError: Error {
    case unknown

    var localizedDescription: String {
        switch self {
        case .unknown:
            return "Unknown error"
        }
    }
}

static let sharedClient = MyAPIClient()
var baseURLString: String? = nil
var baseURL: URL {
    if let urlString = self.baseURLString, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        return url
    } else {
        fatalError()
    }
}

func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String, completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
    let url = self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
    var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
    urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_version", value: apiVersion)]
    var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data,
            let json = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        completion(json, nil)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

**Functions:**

```
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id});
});
```

**When I print out a response in createCustomKey:**

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x28166dc20> { URL: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://us-central1-example-1f886.cloudfunctions.net/ephemeral_keys%253Fapi_version%253D2019-05-16 } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
"Cache-Control" =     (
    "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
);
Date =     (
    "Tue, 14 Apr 2020 10:34:35 GMT"
);
Expires =     (
    "Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
);
Pragma =     (
    "no-cache"
);
Server =     (
    GSE
);
"Set-Cookie" =     (
    "GAPS=1:Rv3nwKVACX7K4OSq4wyvhkby6K_ScA:X1_DgRVnY6h7uHUG;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 14-Apr-2022 10:34:35 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly;Priority=HIGH"
);
"Strict-Transport-Security" =     (
    "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
);
"alt-svc" =     (
    "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\",h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000"
);
"content-security-policy" =     (
    "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-mIemXblM4LXLK6sOz7HVkg' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';report-uri /cspreport"
);
"x-auto-login" =     (
    "realm=com.google&args=service%3Dah%26continue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fappengine.google.com%252F_ah%252Fconflogin%253Fcontinue%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fus-central1-example-1f886.cloudfunctions.net%252Fephemeral_keys%25253Fapi_version%25253D2019-05-16"
);
"x-content-type-options" =     (
    nosniff
);
"x-frame-options" =     (
    DENY
);
"x-xss-protection" =     (
    "1; mode=block"
);
```

Comment: can you try logging `json` or `data` in the app's `createCustomerKey` function to see what the response your server returned? It should be an ephemeral key object obtained on the backend server and passed directly back. (https://github.com/stripe/example-mobile-backend/blob/master/web.rb#L25-L40)

Comment: @karllekko When I print out the response. I've added the return to the question.

Comment: @karllekko But if I try and print out the JSON variable it returns nil.

Comment: that looks like `response` that you logged, what is `data`(the actual HTTP response)?

Comment: @karllekko Data returns `Optional(66327 bytes)`